# redirecting website domain

Tags: redirect, dns

I need some advice,

I have 2 domains, www.example.co.uk and www.example.com.

www.example.com has a large js,php,mysql,flash library behind it with a CMS that I dont really want to have to upload again onto the .co.uk domain.

Assuming this is a fairly simple question, but how to I redirect users from the www.example.co.uk index page to the www.example.com index when they visit it?

I am a complete novice with this sort of thing so might need it broken down fairly simply!!!

Thanks
JD

Comment: You said that you are a complete novice, but if you have ever edited an HTML page you will understand my first suggestion. Leave a comment if you would like any further detail.

Comment: I was referring to adjusting things like the php.ini forms,etc. More than comfortable using your answers to get the results I need. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your current index page on example.co.uk, which I will assume is called index.html, and add the following meta tag to the html header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/">
```

To automatically redirect a visitor after 5 seconds. You should of course also display a message including a link to example.com, asking users to update their bookmarks, etc.

If on the other hand you want to redirect visitors immediately, you can do so in PHP with the header() function by putting the following code in a PHP index page (index.php in the root directory of your site):

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Finally, you can do this at the server level in Apache with a .htaccess file by setting Rewrite rules. This is not generally appropriate for a novice, but if you know that .htaccess files are supported on your server and you aren't using one there is no reason not to try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: just to be clear- using the php header location on the index.php page for example.co.uk? - yup, worked perfectly. Thanks very much! JD